# Kubuntu missing screen lock and screen saver settings

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, lock-screen, plasma-5

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.1 and I am unable to find where to set options for screen locking or screen saver.

[image: Display and Monitor menu]

Version of KDE framework:

[image: About Kubuntu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at *System Settings* → *Desktop Behavior*.

[image: Screen Locking]

Re. a screensaver, that's not included by default because modern screens aren't affected.

But, if you're interested, look at [Where are the screensavers](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/70788-Where-are-the-screensavers).

Answer (score 1):

I have Kubuntu 18.04 - with nVidia drivers..

The problem is that there are TWO places where this is set.

In the setup tool, there is Workspace/Desktop Behavior/Screen Locking - where I can say "Lock screen automatically after:" then enter a time in minutes.

This does not work worth a damn.  I can lock the screen manually - but not have it happen automatically.

However, hidden away under Hardware/Power Management/Energy Saving - there is "Screen Energy Saving" and "Switch off after"...which DOES work.

It's not quite the same thing though because it doesn't lock the screen - and it literally turns the video off rather than displaying a blank screen (or whatever) but for me, it's "good enough".

Screen savers no longer exist without you installing a bunch of extra stuff.  So your lock screen (if you can get it to work) won't be any of the cool animations we used to have.

Comment: sad state of affairs

Answer (score 1):

There are two settings. The *screen locking* and *screen switch off*.

If I want both locking and switch off, it is necessary to switch off the screen after screen locking. Otherwise the lock screen will wake up the screen, which leads to *burn-in* of the screen (more accurately, *image persistence*). What works for me is:

- *Desktop Behavior* → *Screen Locking* → *Activation* → *Lock screen automatically after* → *10 mins*
- *Power management* → *Energy Saving* → *Screen Energy Saving* → *Switch off after* → *15 mins*

This specific behavior may be influenced by my proprietary NVIDIA driver.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can find the screen locking on the *Energy* section of *System Preferences*.There you could choose the locking behavior and many more.

I hope you know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> locks the display window.

The screen saver option was [answered by DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074629/618353).

Answer (score 0):

In kUbuntu 20.04 look at *System Settings* → *Screen Locking*.

There is no *System Settings* → *Desktop Behavior* in my system.